# Why does Python's pathlib and os lib return different results for mapped network drives in Windows?

Tags: python, windows

Trying to resolve a path using Python 3 on Windows 10. The path in question is available as a Mapped Network Drive. (This happens to be done through VirtualBox Shared Folders, but I hope that is not relevant here).

The good old `os.path.abspath` gives me a path that starts with the drive letter that was mapped in Windows. This is exactly what I expected and needed.

But when I try to upgrade to `pathlib`'s `resolve` function, I get a different result, in UNC notation. This is not expected, and not useful for my purposes. (Many programs do not accept UNC paths as input, they require a 'local' path.)

1. What is the reason for this difference?
2. How can one control this behavior so that `pathlib` can return a drive-letter-based path?
3. Can anyone point me to documentation of this? I cannot find it in Python's documentation.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\Users\user> python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import pathlib
>>> path = 'd:\\asdf'
>>> print(os.path.abspath(path))
d:\asdf
>>> print(pathlib.Path(path).resolve())
\\vboxsrv\code\asdf
```

Comment: On Windows, `resolve`  calls `os.path._getfinalpathname`, which calls [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364962). This starts from the final resolved path of the file in the NT namespace (e.g. `\Device\Mup\server\share\...`) and works backward as required to get the `VOLUME_NAME_DOS`. If the final path is a UNC share (i.e. `\Device\Mup`), it returns a path of the form `\\?\UNC\server\share\...`. pathlib translates this back to a regular UNC path of the form `\\server\share\...`.

Comment: `os.path.abspath` calls `os.path._getfullpathname`, which calls [`GetFullPathName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963). This API doesn't use an open file handle and doesn't require that the path even exists. It uses only NT runtime library functions to create a fully qualified path based on the current working directory, or the working directory on the target drive for a drive-relative path.

Comment: Wouldn't `os.path.realpath` correspond to `Path.resolve`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on Windows on parallels on a Mac. It's an ugly fix, but if you know the drive mapping ahead of time you can do something like:

```
filepath = pathlib.Path('.')
filepathstr = str(filepath.resolve()).replace('\\\\Mac\\Home', 'W:')
```